# React Passing props to background url in template literal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning React and I've run into a snag that I can't seem to fix.  In my component that I want the background rendered, I have:

`<BgBackground style={{background: 'url(`{this.props.bg}`)' }} />`

And it takes in it's props from another component with:

`<BgImage bg="about" />`

I'm writing out my template literal (or interpolation?) incorrectly, I know.  I've tried everything such as:

```
{{backgroundImage: `url( "${this.props.bg}" )` }} />
```

And I cannot make it work, what am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

(back tics are included, they don't render in StackO)

Comment: This looks good to me. What does it generate?

Comment: BTW I don't think you need the `"` around the actual url. Just `url(${...})` should work :)

Comment: this returns an error `JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text`

Comment: Are you using a compiler to compile the template literal, or do you relie on your browser to do it?

Comment: as for your first question, it generates nothing.  Like nothing renders at all.  If I do `<h1>this.props.bg</h1>` it'll generate `about` from `<BgImage bg="about" />` just fine

Comment: I'm using yarn to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `""` inside template literals, whole part inside `` will be treated as string and `${}` will be replaced by the value.

Write it like this:

```
{{backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.bg})`}}
```

Reference: [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

**Update:**

Here about is a string (not even a proper image path), import about in this component and pass it like this:

```
import about from 'path';

<BgImage bg={about" />
```

Comment: I get the error `Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ...`

Comment: Actually the `"` is not the problem here. It should work with or without.

Comment: `webpackHotDevClient.js:233 Error in ./src/components/scaffold/bgImage.js
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected ... (30:23)

  28 |     return (
  29 |       <div>
> 30 |         <BgBackground {{backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.bg})`}} />
     |                        ^
  31 |       </div>
  32 |     );
  33 |   }

Error
 @ ./src/components/pages/about.js 18:15-45`

Comment: oops, forgot `style=`

so this throws no errors but it doesn't render anything <BgBackground style={{background: `url(${this.props.bg})`}} />

Comment: but if I write `<BgBackground style={{background: `url(${about})`}} />` it references `import about from '../../static/about.jpg';` just fine and works

Comment: because it doesn't contain a proper image path: `<BgImage bg="about" />`, here "about" is just a string (not even a proper image path), replace this with: `<BgImage bg={about} />` and import the about in that component, it will work

Comment: More than happy to!  One other question, let's say I wanted to wrap with `&::after {}`

how do I write `<BgBackground style={{background: url(${this.props.bg})}} />` correctly with that?

Comment: so it'd be `<BgBackground style={{&::after {background: url(${this.props.bg})}} }/>` (but that's incorrect because it throws an error)

Comment: never tried that, but i think inside `jsx` we can't write this, to achieve this create a `style.css` file and write that part inside that then apply using some `className`.

Comment: awesome thank you for your help and patience, this has been something I've tried to fix for 2 days now.